# sending 2 bits of data from 1 activity to another in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hi I'm trying to learn android programming and I was using the android tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html but then I was going to edit it and add in my own bits and learn from their by using the API guides.

The first editing I wanted to do was to add in a check box that the user could check that would add in another line of text when the final thing was displayed. However I wasn't sure how to add in the check box to the code (in the main activity) and make it send data to the DisplayMessageActivity to tell it to add another line of text under the other line of text that the user defined in the message box, please help (sorry, if I didn't explain it clearly)

Here's the code for the 2 activitys so far if it helps, please be basic with your answers I haven't programmed in a while and Ive barley used java before so I'm still getting to the swing of things.

MainActivity:

```
package com.hyper.benshelloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
/*
* private things can be directly accessed only within the class that defines them.
*•default (i.e., no access modifier) things can be accessed by any code in the same package as the defining class.
*•protected is like default, except subclasses outside of the defining package can also access the member.
*•public members are accessible to all code everywhere.
*/

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.hyper.benshelloworld.MESSAGE";
    //defines the string EXTRA_MESSAGE

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        //calls on DisplayMessageActivity.class
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        //makes the text box writable in.
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        /*receives the typed message and makes it ready to be sent to the 
         * DisplayMessageActivity to be displayed*/
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        /*The most common use of intents is to start new activities (screens)within
         *  an application (line 41). The extras Bundle is a way of passing data between activities. 
         *  Extras are entered as key value pairs so EXTRA_MESSAGE is a key is used to identify a 
         *  particular value so it can be retrieved and used by another activity.
         */

        startActivity(intent);




    }   


}
```

and the DisplayMessageActivity:

```
package com.hyper.benshelloworld;
/*
* private things can be directly accessed only within the class that defines them.
*•default (i.e., no access modifier) things can be accessed by any code in the same package as the defining class.
*•protected is like default, except subclasses outside of the defining package can also access the member.
*•public members are accessible to all code everywhere.
*/

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import java.lang.String;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //receives the intent sent in the MainActivity.class
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        //Uses the getStringExtra to receive the string message from MainActivity in the intent.


        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        /*Sets up a text view to show the string "message" in and
         *sets the size of the text
         */

        if (message.equals("hello world")){
            textView.setText("bit standard");
        }

        setContentView(textView);
        //sets the activity to be showing the textView

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            /* If the android version is 3.0+,  
             * show the Up button in the action bar.
             */
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put multiple things into the extras:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // ...
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(DisplayMessageActivity.KEY_BUNDLE_SOME_VALUE, message);
        bundle.putString(DisplayMessageActivity.KEY_BUNDLE_SOME_OTHER_VALUE, someOtherValue);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    // ...
}
```

In the receiving activity:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_SOME_VALUE = "some_value";
    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_SOME_OTHER_VALUE = "some_other_value";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String string1 = "";
        String string2 = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            if (bundle.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE_SOME_VALUE) {
                string1 = bundle.getString(KEY_BUNDLE_SOME_VALUE);
            }
            if (bundle.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE_SOME_OTHER_VALUE) {
                string2 = bundle.getString(KEY_BUNDLE_SOME_OTHER_VALUE);
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

It's a good idea to add public constants in the receiving activity for the bundle keys.  That will help keep you from making mistakes via typos :)  And if you ever decide to update them they're in 1 spot.